# Updating OneSignal dependency getting Dependency failing error

Tags: android, onesignal

I am getting this Error while updating one signal Dependency.
how can I rectify this??

```
 Dependency failing: com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.12.6 -> com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@[10.2.1, 16.1.99], but play-services-base version was 17.1.0.
```

Answer (score 1):

In your app/build.gradle where you applied the plugin

```
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
```

make sure its is before

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
```

Android studio also gives a warning if the order of the above statements is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

I was missed out updating the `classpath` in dependencies

```
dependencies {
classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.6, 0.99.99]
    }
```

Comment: Did you solved it adding plugin version 0.12.3? Last version is 0.12.6... I'm getting same error, no way to fix it

Comment: I'm getting same error if I upgrade from OneSignal 3.11.4 to 3.12.x versions. Going back to 3.11.4 allows to use any play-services version. I have always set android.enableJetifier=true into gradle.properties file

Comment: No. By Adding below one, only works me. 

`classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.6, 0.99.99]'`